# Java - Time difference in minutes

Tags: java

I have this problem with calculating time difference in minutes.
Its working fine with exampples like calculating the difference between
2045 and 2300.

But when I want to calculate the difference between for example
2330 (today) and 0245 (tomorrow) I get a incorrect answer.
Code below:

```
    // This example works
    String dateStart = "2045";
    String dateStop = "2300";

    // This example doesnt work
    //String dateStart = "2330";
    //String dateStop = "0245";

    // Custom date format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");  

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    

    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);                      
    System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + minutes + " minutes.");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add 1 day to `d2`.

Comment: Think about how your program could know the time is not from the current day.

Comment: @Semith How did you solve your stuff? Was my answer of any help? What is the correct answers? THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working because when you create a new date with just a time in it, it's assuming the day is "today".

What you could do is:

```
// This example works
String dateStart = "2045";
String dateStop = "2300";

// This example doesnt work
//String dateStart = "2330";
//String dateStop = "0245";

// Custom date format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");  

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;
try {
    d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// MY ADDITION TO YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
if(d2.before(d1)){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    c.setTime(d2); 
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    d2 = c.getTime();
}
// ENDS HERE

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);                      
System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + minutes + " minutes.");
```

But you should consider using Java 8 new Date/Time features, or Joda Time.

Comment: Joda time (or the Java 8 functions) is the only reliable way to fix this problem

Comment: While the Java 8 functions are certainly an improvement, I consider the answer fully reliable and I challenge you, @Stormcloud, to point out in what way it isn’t (I don’t know Joda time well enough to have a qualified opinion).

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. And could you link me to the new Java 8 function? Still kinda new to Java and dont know about the new function

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes from `java.time.*` package introduced in Java 8. They are very handy in use as they can address various corner cases (e.g. measuring minutes across different time zones, or during autumn and spring time change).

The thing to you need to know when you calculate time difference is that:

- **LocalTime** contains time only
- **LocalDate** contains date only (no time)
- **LocalDateTime** contains both (date + time.)
- **ZonedDateTime** contains date + time + timezone

This implies that difference between times will be different when you compare with:

- **LocalTime** you can diff only time so **20:45** and **23:30** gives 2:45 of difference
- **LocalDate** you cannot calculate any time diffs (contains no time)
- **LocalDateTime** you can specify date and time, e.g.: **20:45 on 1Jan** and **23:30 on 3Jan** . Time difference will be 2:45 and 2 days of difference, or 50:45.
- **ZonedDateTime** - same as **LocalDateTime** plus you takes into account DayLightSavings, so if the clock is changed overnight - it will get reflected.

Here is a snippet for a **LocalDateTime**:

```
    LocalDateTime today2045    = LocalDateTime.of(
            LocalDate.now(),
            LocalTime.parse("20:45"));
    LocalDateTime tomorrow0230 = LocalDateTime.of(
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(1),
            LocalTime.parse("02:30"));

    System.out.println("Difference [minutes]: " + 
            Duration.between(today2045, tomorrow0230).toMinutes());
```

For **ZonedDateTime** taking into account spring/autumn clock changes:

```
    ZonedDateTime today2045    = ZonedDateTime.of(
            LocalDate.now(),
            LocalTime.parse("20:45"),
            ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime tomorrow0230 = ZonedDateTime.of(
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(1),
            LocalTime.parse("02:30"),
            ZoneId.systemDefault());

    System.out.println("Difference [minutes]: " + 
            Duration.between(today2045, tomorrow0230).toMinutes());
```

Some info on constructors can be found in [Oracle's tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html).

Comment: Why downvoting? This answers the questions and is in line with latest recommendation(???).

Comment: Perhaps down vote is because of posting the same material in two Answers on this Question?

Comment: @Basil Bourqe : Nope. This one got the down vote first. I think I was editing it and by the time I finished - I got the down vote.

Comment: (A) I'll gladly upvote when you cleanup and consolidate into a single Answer. (B) I suggest using the name 'java.time' rather than 'Java 8' as that name will not age well. (C) Code snippets might be easier to read than your complete class with contrived `for` loop. As a supplement, you could put complete code in an online tool like IdeOne.com and link to it from your Answer if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Especially one about snippets.  Will keep that in mind and work through the changes later on today.

Comment: Better, but should be using `ZonedDateTime` with a `ZoneId` rather than `LocalDateTime`. The `Local…` types purposely lack any concept of offset-from-UTC or time zone. A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent an actual moment on the timeline. So if the date in question happens to be anomalous such as the cut-over day for Daylight Saving Time (DST) in your time zone, **this Answer’s code will return incorrect results**. Search Stack Overflow for `ZonedDateTime` to see many examples.

Comment: The examples reflects now ZonedDateTime. Made in time for autumn clock change! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add if statement to check if this is today, and if no you can add one day to this, since you are comparing time it wont be problem if you add full day

```
    if(d2.before(d1)){
        d2.setTime(d2.getTime()+86400000);
    }
```

Try it out

Comment: This is much more better than my original way to do it in my answer. I've updated my answer with your code. Thanks!

Comment: 86400000 assumes that all days have exactly 24 hours. This fails for daylight savings

Comment: It doesn't since it always adds 24 hours to 1 January 1970

Answer (score -1):

This is a solved problem. If you look at the Joda Time library you'll find all the time and date manipulation functions you could possibly want:

In your case something along the lines of:

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(larger-time);
DateTime second = new DateTime(smaller-time);
DateTime difference = first.minusMillis(second.getMillis())
```

Joda will cope with all the odd edge conditions like rolling over between days/months/years, lengths of months, leap years, daylight savings, timezones...

Comment: Wow! a ton of down votes for using a well respected library. Any body care to explain why

Comment: The initial version of your response had no usable answer, only a suggestion to go look at a library.  That said, why incur a dependency on a third-party library when [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is basically the same thing and requires no dependencies?

Comment: Ah, yes. I put together a quick answer and then edited it to include an example. When I had finished I had 3 down votes - less than 3 minutes! Even worse, the upvoted answers won't work in all cases.
You are right that java.time is the same thing, but it's Java 8 only.

Comment: Some factual corrections… Joda-Time is *not* the same thing as java.time. They share some basic concepts, and share some class/method names, and share the same leader (Stephen Colbourne), but are distinct from one another. Joda-Time inspired java.time, but now Joda-Time is in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to java.time classes. Yes, java.time is built into Java SE 8, with minor features and fixes added in Java SE 9. But much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted for Android in ThreeTenABP.

Comment: I understood the question as finding the difference in minutes between for example `"2330"` (today) and `"0245"` (tomorrow). I can’t see you’ve answered it.