# How to convert a time whch given in string and find the difference in java and convert back to string

Tags: java, string, time

I have following time for a given day which is in sting format.

```
      "begin_time_tz": "00:00 DST",
      "end_time_tz": "07:30 DST",
```

I have to find the difference between them in java. Please help me to find the difference and convert back to string

Note: Date is in 24 hour format(00:00 -- 23:59)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Duplicates: [Time difference in minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40285248/642706) and [Time difference in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16948799/642706)

Comment: Yet another duplicate: [How do I measure elapsed time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1770010/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below method to get the time difference, just pass HH:MM without the timezone.

```
public long getTimeDifference(String time1, String time2) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
        Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
        long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        return difference/1000;
    }
```

Comment: In this logic we are missing the 00:30 duration

Comment: No, i am getting the getTimeDifference("00:00","07:30") = 27000 Seconds = 450 Minutes = 7 hours and 30 minutes

Comment: You can use the formulas to convert from seconds to Hour, Minute, Seconds as `long hours = totalSecs / 3600;`
  `long minutes = (totalSecs % 3600) / 60;`
  `long seconds = totalSecs % 60;`

Comment: Thanks Umais Gillani

Answer (score 0):

using Java8 DateTime API we can get the `Duration` between two `LocalTime`

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
    String[] arr = new String[] { "00:00", "07:30" };
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(arr[0], formatter);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(arr[1], formatter);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
    System.out.println(duration);
```

output

```
PT7H30M
```

Hour minute conversion

```
static final int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60;
static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
static final int SECONDS_PER_HOUR = SECONDS_PER_MINUTE * MINUTES_PER_HOUR;

long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
long hours = seconds / SECONDS_PER_HOUR;
int minutes = (int) ((seconds % SECONDS_PER_HOUR) / SECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
System.out.println("Duration " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes ");
```

output

```
Duration 7 hours 30 minutes
```